# How to update serialize data in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, serialization

I have this serialize data in my mySQL database

```
a:4:{i:0;s:7:"bvl.png";i:1;s:8:"ccop.jpg";i:2;s:11:"reyborn.png";i:3;s:13:"swopgroup.jpg";}
```

How can I update this data, for example I want to delete `ccop.jpg`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to fetch the value from the database, unserialize it, remove the element, serialize it and save again.

```
$remove = "ccop.jpg";

//
// get the string from the database
//

$arr = unserialize($str);

foreach($arr as $key => $value)
  if ($value == $remove) unset($arr[$key]);

$str = serialize($arr);

//
// save the string back to the database
//
```

---

Instead of saving serialized list of values, it's better to have a [normalized database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and just do a simple `DELETE FROM images WHERE object_id = ...`.

Comment: Thank you for the idea, if I could only decide I will probably do that, but unfortunately I just doing the php code I can't alter the database table definition, that is why I am looking an alternative way.

Answer (score 7):

## Do not store serialized data in database.

Create a linked table consists of `main_id` and `picture` and store your image names in it.
So, you will have distinct access to them.

Comment: why I don't save serialize data to mysql database ?

Comment: Unless your database is a wordpress database, then you'll just be forever in a world of hurt.

Comment: Unless your database is a wordpress database, then you'll just be forever in a world of hurt.

Answer (score 4):

Ideally you need to

- extract it
- deserialize it
- modify it
- serialize it
- write it back to the database.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are storing it in a VARCHAR field and it is a PHP serialized array you would want to pull it out of the database unserialize and then re-update the field.  You shouldn't look to MySQL to modify PHP specific information because well ... that's not what it is made for.

Comment: Thank you gentlement you save my day :)