# Save location to database

Tags: mysql, arrays, json, google-maps, path

As a part of Our university project we have to save the path of boats as a set of coordinates. There are more than 50,000 boats. A gadget on each boat will send the current location (latitudes and longitudes) and other data as well every 10 minutes. using this data, we need to display the path of each boat and also save each day's data to view another day.

After receiving that data, we have to save it in a mySQL database. Each new transmission should be saved to a new row and not overwrite the previous location.

We tried to create a JSON array with all the data:

```
boat_path =
    [{"lat": -33.8919, "lng": 151.1360 ,"bateryState"=89 , "Help","no"},
    {"lat": -33.897, "lng: 151.0996},"bateryState"=78 , "Help","no"}];
```

Our idea was save this json array in a particular field and when new data is received, we would overwrite the previous one. However, the problem is mysql 5.6 does not support JSON arrays. Is there another method of doing this?

If this is not the suitable way, what is?

another method to do this
[image: another method to do this]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update serialize data in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612622/how-to-update-serialize-data-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the wrong way of using a database. What I would do is create a table with the following fields:

1. Boat_ID
2. Timestamp
3. Longtitude
4. Latitude
5. ...

Each transmission would be added as a row with an INSERT SQL operation. Plotting paths would work by doing an SQL SELECT * WHERE Boat_ID=x ORDERED BY Timestamp.

JSON is one good way to send the data to the database, but the server side should parse it and load its components to the database separately. That way, you could query specific boats and order the results by timestamp, making the plotting function easier.

*Note: I don't do SQL on a daily basis, so consider the above more in the way of pseudo code.*

Comment: thank you. But the problem is this, let assume there are 50000 boats. and each boat send data every 10 minutes. so that for 1 day, 1 boat will send 10*6*24 = 1440 times data. that mean for 1 boat,for one day it will cost 1440 rows. for 50000 boats it will cost 72000000 raws. is possible to handle ?

Comment: Sure. These numbers don't belong in a homework project, but this really is the way to go. I'm even less of an expert in DBA but from peripheral knowledge a big server with attached fast storage, use of partitions (once a week?). Place each boat in a different table. etc.  http://dba.stackexchange.com/ is really the place to ask how to do the db part right.

Comment: yes. I also think that maintain separate table for each boat. I'll try it. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

> However, the problem is mysql 5.6 does not support JSON arrays.

What do you mean MySQL doesn't support JSON arrays?

[Your JSON can be deserialized as a string on its way into the database and then re-serialized as a JSON array after retrieval from the database.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5336113/109941)

JSON is just a serialization medium, nothing more. If you choose to architect your application such that the UI exchanges JSON with the server, then so be it. It's orthogonal and mostly irrelevant to how the data is stored.

Comment: I mean that "MySQL doesn't support JSON arrays", we can not insert json object as it is(without convert as strings). just think every time data receive, 1) get the string from database 
2) create json object using that string(re-serialized)
3) insert data
4) convert json array to string(deserializing)
5) inser to the database.

so we have to handle 50000+ boats. each boat will send data every 10 min. So I feel that this process will take time.(I don't know exactly.) That's why I try to store json array as it, In the database.Without converting.